# iOS black screen after splash screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, orientation, device-orientation

I have a slight problem with my application, which was done under ionic, in AngularJS.

The application launches and works very well under android, but on the iOS part, just after the splash screen, it gives me a black screen.

So I can access my index, which is a login page, I need to rotate the device, or that I orient it in landscape. After doing this, the application works very well, whether in portrait or landscape, I do not understand anything..

I would like to know what is happening, since on Xcode I tried everything ..

here is what I did, I even made it only in portrait, but nothing helps
[image]

Thank you for your answers.